# Multi Screen Scale "a " Serious Problem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

Please Consider my below xml code and screen shot(To view the large screen shotplease click on Large Screen Link ,the first one is the screen shot of small screen ).

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                        android:clipChildren="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/default1"
                        android:weightSum="10"
                    >

        <ImageView 
                        android:id="@+id/FrameLayout01" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                        android:background="@drawable/fc_postyour_best_score_bg"
        />  

        </LinearLayout>
```

By viewing the screen shot you can get idea that CANICA logo Image is go far than the large screen.

Now I have also made images accordingly to the devices dpi and screen dimension and put them in hdpi,mdpi,ldpi folders and I get the desired and perfect smiler look in all devices(small,medium,large),

But the issue is that I have to use many Imagebuttons and ToggleButtons in this xml files and I have few more xml  file like that.

So making these images according to the drawable folders will increase my app size more and more , and I think there should be a way to rid out of this problem and optimize my  app size......

SO,if anybody know the way please help me

[image: Small Screen]

[Large screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNUDb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your app look the same on all devices you must provide resources for all screen densities. That's compromise between quality and app size.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay --- but there should be something to maintain both